# How to get first name and last name from facebook?

Tags: laravel

I have tried implementing first name and last name of the person trying to authenticate from facebook. I have seen lots of tutorials and followed them accordingly but couldn't get it.

I have tried

```
    $user = Member::create([
       'first_name'=> $providerUser->getFirstName(),
       'last_name'=>$providerUser->getLastName(),
       'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
       'profilepic'=>$providerUser->getAvatar(),
       'password' => md5(rand(1,10000)),
    ]);
```

Comment: try `dd($providerUser)` you can see how many  data you are getting you can use that

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the provider you use is [socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite), to get last name ans first name you can use `$providerUser->user['first_name']` and `$providerUser->user['last_name']`

So based your code:

```
$user = Member::create([
   'first_name'=> $providerUser->user['first_name'],
   'last_name'=>$providerUser->user['last_name'],
   'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
   'profilepic'=>$providerUser->getAvatar(),
   'password' => md5(rand(1,10000)),
]);
```

Comment: May be it is `$providerUser['first_name']`

Comment: @TesushInternational please show how you  create `$providerUser` or return of `dd($providerUser)`

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur i have die dump $providedUser and there is no first_name and Last_name provided

Comment: so, please show me how you create $providerUser , I think it's the problem